# Sort SharePoint sub-sites with columns?

Tags: navigation, sub-site

I have a site that is starting to contain multiple sub-sites. One per project. I would like to add some columns to the site list. I have not be able to find an easy way of howto do this. Any ideas? Below is the view of the sites and where i would like to add the columns. Its from the _layouts/viewlsts.aspx?ShowSites=1 page.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe what you are trying to do is possible, as this is an OOTB layouts page, rather than a list. However, it would be fairly simple to create a 'Project Sub-Sites' list within your top-level site, and add whatever additional columns you require. This would require manually updating on each new site creation.

If you wanted to go a custom-code route, you could look into the `WebProvisioned` event receiver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Well dang.... thats an easy fix!